# NoMethodError for responds_with when switching to mongoid-rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, rspec-rails, shoulda

I was initially writing tests for my models and controllers with shoulda-matchers, but then I realised that I had to use mongoid-rspec because I'm using Mongoid.

The problem is that if I replace `shoulda-matchers` with `mongoid-rspec`, my model tests are ok, but I get a `NoMethodError` for `responds_with` methods.

Is there any way I can specify to use `shoulda-matchers` for controllers and `mongoid-rspec` for models exclusively, or a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

As long as `mongoid-rspec` doesn't define matchers that are named the same as those in `shoulda-matchers`, then you should be able to keep both gems in your Gemfile.

If this is not the case and the two conflict with each other, and assuming you're still on the 2.x line, then I'm afraid there isn't anything you can do. 3.0 contains a fix whereby only model matchers are mixed into model example groups and controller matchers are mixed into controller example groups, though it also contains [other backward incompatible changes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/NEWS.md#300) that you'll want to be aware of.